# In what year was the letter to the Galatians written?

Tags: paul-apostle, authorship, galatians

I found conflicting sources on the internet:

1. [The first source](http://www.christianitytoday.com/history/issues/issue-47/apostle-paul-and-his-times-christian-history-timeline.html) said the Letter to the Galatians was written between 52-55 AD.
2. [The second source](http://www.esvbible.org/resources/esv-global-study-bible/chart_40_00_nt_timeline/#chart_40_00_nt_timeline-star-1) said it was written between 48-49 AD.

Just comparing the dates did not interest me.  When I see the relationship with the Jerusalem Council, it becomes more interesting.

1. The first source put the Jerusalem council before the writing of
   the Galatian letter.
2. The second source put the writing of the Galatian letter before the
   Jerusalem council. (To be honest, I myself prefer the second source for my own reason).

But since I'm not an expert, I wonder at the different timing between two source?

**Which source is correct ?**

Comment: Scholars don't know when it was written, though some have favorite theories placing it in one period or other.  For example, some argue that since Galatians does not mention the judgment against Judiazers at council of Jerusalem (dated sometimes to c.50 CE), the epistle must come before that time. Then again, we don't really know for sure when the council of Jerusalem was either, and it may not have happened as described in Acts anyway (meaning that Paul may not have had reason to mention it in Galatians). That said, beware of non-scholarly "sources" that give empty dates without argument.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the explanation. 

My reason to choose the second source is because when Paul said "Peter was afraid of those who belonged to the circumcision group" - I don't think Paul will say like that if Galatian was written after Jerusalem Council. If Galatian was written after Jerusalem Council, how could Paul say like that when he himself knew that Peter reconciled the dispute among the brethren at the Jerusalem Council ?

Comment: Since Paul was taking up a collection for the 'poor' in Jerusalem, the letter could even have been written at the time of the great famine of the mid-forties, although this creates problems for the chronologies of Luke-Acts.

Comment: @BenWallis Looks to me like you have an answer.